# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'administration/portfolio%20'

Tags: angular

In the menu, when I click on `Portfolio`, the page does not display.

By doing a console.log, I see that I have an error message:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'administration/portfolio%20'
```

[image]

I don't understand why the path is `administration/portfolio%20` and not `administration/portfolio`? Why the value `%20` is added?

Here is the structure of the project

[image]

I think I have a problem with the routes?

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/dashboard/dashboard.module').then((m) => m.DashboardModule),
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**dashboard-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

const DASHBOARD_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'administration',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/administration/administration.module').then((m) => m.AdministrationModule),
      },
  
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(DASHBOARD_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {}
```

**administration-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../../dashboard.component';



import { PortfolioComponent } from './views/portfolio/portfolio.component';

export const ADMINISTRATION_ROUTES: Routes = [
 
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,

  }, 
  
  {
    path: 'portfolio',
    component: PortfolioComponent,
  },

 

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(ADMINISTRATION_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AdministrationRoutingModule {}
```

Here is also a reproduction of the project -> [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-tdjwfx?file=src/app/views/dashboard/views/administration/administration-routing.module.ts).

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your dashboard.component.html:

```
<a routerLink="{{ submenu.url }} "
```

should be

```
<a routerLink="{{ submenu.url }}"
```

This matches because `%20` is a space.